# Jenkins and using the iterator-maven-plugin with multiple databases

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sql-server-2012, iterator

I need to create multiple MS SQL databases via Jenkins. I'm using the sql-maven-plugin, which works fine with one database.

However, I need to create multiple databases, and so tried to use the iterator-maven-plugin to iterate over the databases. However, I'm having issues with the iterator picking up the driver.

I'm getting this error, but from the pom.xml it seems I added the driver:

*Failed to execute goal com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:0.3:iterator (default) on project UNIT4-db_EXECUTE: Unable to parse configuration of mojo com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:0.3:iterator for parameter driver: Cannot find 'driver' in class java.lang.Object -> [Help 1]*

- How can I resolve this issue?
- Is there a better / easier way to execute SQL over multiple
  databases?

Here is a snippet of the pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.3</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
          <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
          <version>4.0</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>iterator</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <items>
              <item>database1</item>
              <item>database2</item>
              <item>database3</item>
            </items>
            <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:sqlserver://databasehostname:1234;databaseName=@item@;instanceName=mssqlserver2012</url>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pass</password>
            <pluginExecutors>
              <pluginExecutor>
                <!-- ADD MS SQL executor here -->
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.5</version>
                  <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                      <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                      <version>4.0</version>
                      <scope>system</scope>
                      <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                  </dependencies>
                  <configuration>
                    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://UNIT4-GODATA1:1433;databaseName=@item@;instanceName=mssqlserver2012</url>
                    <username>unit4_jenkins_test</username>
                    <password>unit4_jenkins_test</password>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>execute-pre-deploy-scripts</id>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                        <delimiter>GO</delimiter>
                        <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <fileset>
                          <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                          <includes>
                            <include>@item@/Pre Deploy Scripts/*.sql</include>
                          </includes>
                        </fileset>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                      <id>create-types-data</id>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                        <delimiter>GO</delimiter>
                        <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <fileset>
                          <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                          <includes>
                            <include>@item@/Programmability/Types/User Defined Data Types/*.sql</include>
                          </includes>
                        </fileset>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
              </pluginExecutor>
            </pluginExecutors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I'd like to add that this is most likely 'not the right tool for the job', but was asked to do this.

Comment: If i correctly see that you have defined the microsoft driver being a dependency of the iterator-maven-plugin which might be wrong..

Comment: I removed the MS driver dependency of the iterator-maven-plugin, and still get the same issue. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: You have to remove the `executions` in the pluginExecutor cause the `pluginExecutor` already defines the execution. For example you can take a look [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/it/mavenAssemblyPluginWithPropertiesTest/pom.xml).

Answer (score 3):

This works now. Thanks [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) for the guidance.

Here is a snippet of a working pom.xml ( unformatted ).

```
<build>


<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>iterator</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <items>
              <item>database1</item>
              <item>database2</item>
              <item>database3</item>
            </items>
            <pluginExecutors>
             <pluginExecutor>
               <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                 <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>1.5</version>
                 <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                     <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                     <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                     <version>4.0</version>
                     <scope>system</scope>
                     <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
                   </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
               </plugin>
               <goal>execute</goal>
               <configuration>
                 <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>        
                 <url>jdbc:sqlserver://mydb:1433;databaseName=@item@;instanceName=mssqlserver2012</url>
                 <username>dbuser</username>
                 <password>dbuser</password>
                 <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                 <delimiter>GO</delimiter>
                 <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
                 <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                 <fileset>
                   <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                   <includes>
                     <include>Database/@item@/Types Data Scripts/*.sql</include>
                   </includes>
                 </fileset>
               </configuration>
             </pluginExecutor>
             <pluginExecutor>
               <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                 <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>1.5</version>
                 <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                     <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                     <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                     <version>4.0</version>
                     <scope>system</scope>
                     <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
                   </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
               </plugin>
               <goal>execute</goal>
               <configuration>
                 <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>                
                 <url>jdbc:sqlserver://mydb:1433;databaseName=@item@;instanceName=mssqlserver2012</url>
                 <username>dbuser</username>
                 <password>dbuser</password>
                 <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                 <delimiter>GO</delimiter>
                 <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
                 <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                 <fileset>
                   <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                   <includes>
                     <include>Database/@item@/Create Tables Scripts/*.sql</include>
                   </includes>
                 </fileset>
               </configuration>
             </pluginExecutor>
           </pluginExecutors>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```